# Probability in ball coloring

Tags: probability, combinatorics, asymptotics, balls-in-bins

You have exactly $n^2$ balls each one of which can be colored in one of $n^2$ ways. That is total colors is $n^2$ but I am not saying all the $n^{2}$ balls are distinctly colored. However assume each ball can be given a color $i$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$ (uniform probability of assignment of colors). You pick $n^{b}$ balls without replacement. What is the probability that atleast $n^{a}$ balls are of the same color with $0 < a < b \leq 2$? Floor any real numbers to get integers - in any case - I am looking for asymptotic bounds.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: Are $a$, $b$, and $n$ exponents?  Are we to assume that $a$ and $b$ are either $0$,$1$, or $2$, or can they be arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: What do you mean? All $a,b,n$ are variables. If it helps analysis, you could substitute constants.

Comment: Is $a=1.5$ allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are drawing with replacement.  We assume you want exactly $n^a$ that match, with the rest non-matching.  If you just want at least $n^a$, you have to sum over $n^a$ up to $n^b$.  If $2n^a \gt n^b$ it is easier, as you can't get two sets of the same color.  There are $(n^2)^{(n^b)}$ ordered draws.  To get $n^a$ that match, you can choose the positions of the matching ones in ${n^b \choose n^a}$ ways, the color in $n^2$ ways, and the remaining colors in $(n^2-1)^{(n^b-n^a)}$ ways.  So we have a probability of $$\frac {{n^b \choose n^a}n^2(n^2-1)^{(n^b-n^a)}}{(n^2)^{(n^b)}}$$
This will overcount if $2n^a \le n^b$ because times you get two groups of $n^a$ are counted twice and so on.  There is no magic in making everything powers of $n$-you could as easily use $a,b,n$ for the numbers.  It should be clear how to modify the expression to do that.

Comment: I do not want replacement.

Comment: If you don't want replacement, you can't get more than one ball of a given color.  The probability is zero.

Comment: Why is probability $0$? I did not say all the $n^{2}$ balls are distinctly colored. There are just $n^2$ colors to choose from for each ball. You could have all the $n^{2}$ balls colored to be same in  the beginning by chance. I am guessing it scales $(\frac{1}{n^{2}})^{(n^{a})}$.

Comment: Then you have to specify the distribution.  If the colors are randomly picked, you will have a Poisson distribution with mean $1$.  About $\frac 1e$ of the colors will be absent, about $\frac 1e$ will have only one marble, others will have a few more.  The chance of getting any reasonable number of matches is still *very* small.

Comment: Assume each ball can be given a color $i$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$ (assigning each color has same probability for any given ball)

Comment: That was the random pick I describe above.

Comment: So is the very small number you are mentioning asymptotically $(\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^{a}}$ independent of $b$ if $b > a$?

Comment: I had some exponents backwards, now fixed. The top exponent in the denominator is $b$, not $a$ (and not $2$).  Basically, you have so many colors (assuming $n$ isn't too small) that you can't get very many matches.

Comment: So asymptotically ${n^{(b-a-2)n^{a}}}$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't have to account for initially choosing the $n^b$ balls out of $n^2$. In particular, we could start with just $n^b$ balls and ask what is the probability that at least $n^a$ have the same color. Let $X$ denote the number of sets of $n^a$ balls of the same color, so we wish to bound the probability that $X$ is at least 1. So
\begin{align*}
P(X \geq 1) \leq E[X] &= \sum_{A : |A|=n^a} P(\text{the balls of }A\text{ are mono colored})
\end{align*}
For any specific such set of balls $A$, note that this probability is exactly 
$$\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{|A|-1},$$
since the first ball can be any color, but each of the following balls of $A$ must be the same as the first one.

Hence
\begin{align*}
P(X \geq 1) &\leq {n^b \choose n^a} \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{n^a-1} \leq \left( \frac{e n^b}{n^a} \right)^{n^a} \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{n^a-1} \\& \leq n^2 \left( \frac{e n^b}{n^a n^2} \right)^{n^a}=\exp \left( -n^a(2-b+a)\ln n+o(n^a \ln n)\right).
\end{align*}